# Replacing null/blank data returned by Scrapy.css with string "None"

Tags: python, css, scrapy

I am using Python.org version 2.7 64 bit on Windows Vista 64 bit. I have the following code extract that creates a string from the contents of part of a HTML table:

...

```
for row in rows

    incident = " ".join( row.css('.incidents-icon::attr(title)').extract() ).strip() + ','

    incident1 = str(incident) 
        if incident1 == "":
            incident1 = "None"
```

The string incident1 then writes out to a .csv file along with other variables. This all works great, however sometimes no results are returned from the table, so I want to replace these with the word "None".

I have also tried:

```
incident1 = str(incident) 
        if not incident1:
            incident1 = "None"
```

I realise that there are several examples on Stack Overflow of questions around null or empty strings, however the answers given do not seem to be resolving my issue. In the first example the code executes fine, however null/blank strings are still returned. In the second one the code does not execute correctly. It does not error, but the program does not iterate over all rows in the table and does not write an output to the .csv file. To put this into context my full code is below:

```
from scrapy.spider import Spider
from scrapy.selector import Selector
from scrapy.utils.markup import remove_tags
from scrapy.cmdline import execute
import csv


class MySpider(Spider):

    name = "goal2"
    allowed_domains = ["whoscored.com"]
    start_urls = ["http://www.whoscored.com/Players/3859/Fixtures/Wayne-Rooney"]    

    def parse(self, response):
        sel = Selector(response)

        titles = sel.xpath("normalize-space(//title)")
        print 'titles:', titles.extract()[0]

        rows = sel.xpath('//table[@id="player-fixture"]//tbody//tr')

        for row in rows:

            print 'date:', "".join( row.css('.date::text').extract() ).strip()
            print 'result:', "".join( row.css('.result a::text').extract() ).strip()
            print 'team_home:', "".join( row.css('.team.home a::text').extract() ).strip()
            print 'team_away:', "".join( row.css('.team.away a::text').extract() ).strip()
            print 'info:', "".join( row.css('.info::text').extract() ).strip(), "".join( row.css('.info::attr(title)').extract() ).strip()
            print 'rating:', "".join( row.css('.rating::text').extract() ).strip()
            print 'incidents:', ", ".join( row.css('.incidents-icon::attr(title)').extract() ).strip()
            print '-'*40

            date = "".join( row.css('.date::text').extract() ).strip() + ','
            result = "".join( row.css('.result a::text').extract() ).strip() + ','
            team_home = "".join( row.css('.team.home a::text').extract() ).strip() + ','
            team_away = "".join( row.css('.team.away a::text').extract() ).strip() + ','
            info = "".join( row.css('.info::text').extract() ).strip() + ','
            rating = "".join( row.css('.rating::text').extract() ).strip() + ','
            incident = " ".join( row.css('.incidents-icon::attr(title)').extract() ).strip() + ','

            date1 = str(date)
            if date1 == "":
                date1 = "None"
            result1 = str(result)
            #if not result1:
                #result1 = "None"
            team_home1 = str(team_home)
            #if not home1:
                #home1 = "None"
            team_away1 = str(team_away)
            #if not team_away1:
                #team_away1 = "None"
            info1 = str(info)
            #if not info1:
                #info1 = "None"
            rating1 = str(rating)
            #if not rating1:
                #rating1 = "None"
            incident1 = str(incident) 
            if incident1 == "":
                incident1 = "None"

            mystring = date1 + result1 + team_home1 + team_away1 + info1 + rating1 + incident1 
            #print remove_tags(mystring).encode('utf-8')

            filepath = "C:\\Python27\\Football Data\\test" + ".txt"



            with open(filepath, "a") as f:
                f.write(mystring)
                f.close()



execute(['scrapy','crawl','goal2'])
```

I thought because the .css function has a .strip() instance in it that this would ensure that the field is not just returning all white spaces. Is the variable being created using .css literally going to resolve to "" if no matching data is found in that row of the table? Is so, why is my first example not working? If not, what syntax should I use instead?

Thanks

Comment: @furas can you see why the above logic is not working? seems to me like it should...

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that I am adding a ',' to the end of the string to act as a separator in the .csv file, so a variable where no goals or assists etc happened will resolve to "," and not "". I've amended the logic now.

Answer (score 0):

From What I'm understanding is that you are trying to access an attribute from css and when it returns (""), instead of this you want it to return "None" in this case what you have to do is:

```
incident = row.css('.incidents-icon::attr(title)').get(default='None')
```

What this will do is return a default value when the result is empty